# Kubuntu 20 is not booted (started) after being removed and reinstalled alongside Windows 10

Tags: grub, kubuntu

I had a Kubuntu 20.04 installed alongside Windows 10. I needed to remove it; hence in disk management of Windows I deleted the Kubuntu partitions. I had some problems with Grub but in each restarting of the PC, I selected the BIOS mode and then, from the boot menu, I selected Windows.

But now I need Kubuntu again and reinstalled it using a live USB. When I power on the PC, the Grub menu is displayed with two options for Windows and Ubuntu. Whenever I select the Ubuntu option, the motherboard name is displayed and nothing happens afterwards.

What can I do? Should I change something in the 'grub' settings? I should mention that I have access to grub setting via a live USB.

Comment: You need to understand UEFI and its boot process. Namely understand that by removing the former Kubuntu system partition (and other eventually) that alone doesn't remove its boot entry in the ESP (EFI System Partition). You need to familiarize yourself with your own, specific, firmware (UEFI ("BIOS")) and know exactly where and how to manage the boot order. Here's what's likely happening: You're still trying to boot the old entry that now can't possibly work. So, you need to select the correct one for starters (trial and error may be the way).

Comment: Once you boot into Kubuntu make sure to run `sudo update-grub` but even before that make sure to disable Fast Startup in Windows and shutdown (Windows) properly.